# AppData folder of user who runs application

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, appdata

**I'm currently using** this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

to access the AppData folder of the user logged in. The result is a path like this:

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Michael\\Application Data"
```

**But:** To run the program on another user, I start a new Process like this:

```
try {    
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
        FileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
        UserName = txtWinLoginUsername.Text,
        Password = txtWinLoginPassword.SecurePassword,
        Domain = this.domain,
        UseShellExecute = false, //kein Plan
    };
    //start program
    Process.Start(processInfo); //execute
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(); //close current Window if it worked
} catch {
    //Windows login failed //reset PasswordBox etc.
}
```

and kill the current one.

So what I want is the new AppData folder but the AppData call results in the default one:

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Default\\Application Data"
```

**What I need** is the ApplicationData of the user of the thread my program is working in. AND I don't like to use something like Substring (Only if I have to :)

Comment: Has that user ever logged in to that machine before? If not, then they won't have a folder yet. Also, have you tried setting `LoadUserProfile = true` in your `ProcessStartInfo` object?

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)) + "ProgramData"` like "C:\ProgramData" can not be accessed by other user. How can I fix it

Comment: You are asking different questions now.

Comment: I'm sorry,
I should thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `LoadUserProfile = true` in your `ProcessStartInfo` otherwise the users profile is not available:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
    UserName = txtWinLoginUsername.Text,
    Password = txtWinLoginPassword.SecurePassword,
    Domain = this.domain,
    UseShellExecute = false, //kein Plan
    LoadUserProfile = true
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //Add this line
};
```